# A question about fields of fraction

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I know that defining a field of fraction, is a way to extend a ring to a field, and also I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$.
Or Guassian rationals are field of fraction of Guassian integers. But I don't know how I can prove it or what is the first step for proof.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: For example, prove $\;\Bbb Q\;$ is a field containing (an isomorphic copy of) $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , and it is contained in any other field containing $\;\Bbb Z\;$ . By the minimality of the field of fractions this is enough. The same with Gaussian integers.

Answer (score 0):

A field $F$ is a field of fractions of a domain $R$ if

1. there exists an injective ring homomorphism $j\colon R\to F$;
2. every element of $F$ is of the form $j(a)j(b)^{-1}$ for some $a,b\in R$, $b\ne0$.

Condition 1 holds if $R$ is a subring of $F$, taking the inclusion as $j$.

It can be proved that, if $F_1$ and $F_2$ are fields of fractions of $R$, via the injective homomorphisms $j_1\colon R\to F_1$ and $j_2\colon R\to F_2$, then there exists a *unique* ring homomorphism $f\colon F_1\to F_2$ such that $f\circ j_1=j_2$.

Can you prove the conditions for $\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}$ or for $\mathbb{Z}[i]\subset\mathbb{Q}[i]$?

---

The elements of $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ can be written as
$$
\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}i=\frac{ad}{bd}+\frac{bc}{bd}i=(ad+bci)(bd)^{-1}
$$
and this is of the requested form, because $bd\in\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: It was helpful, but for Z[i] is a bit confusing.thanks

Comment: @gmath Integers are particular cases of Gaussian integers.